# google places autocomplete webservice do not return postal code

Tags: web-services

curl --location 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=18%20Camp&key='

Is there a way to return the postal code in this api call
I tried with many other parameters as per the documentation and none of them returns the postal.
I want to use the server side webservice api and not the client side javascript